# What is hogging my connection?

Tags: wireless, networking

At times it seems like dozens, if not hundreds of root-owned HTTP connections spring up.
This is not much of a problem on LAN or WLAN as each of them seems to transfer very little, but if I use GPRS link, my ping times go into minutes (seriously, 80000ms is not infrequent!) and all connections grind to a halt waiting till these end.

This usually lasts some 15 minutes and ends about when I start troubleshooting it for real.

I've managed to capture a fragment of Nethogs output

```
   NetHogs version 0.8.0

     PID USER     PROGRAM                                                                                     DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
   ?     root     37.209.147.180:59854-141.101.114.59:80                                                                 0.013       0.000 KB/sec
   ?     root     37.209.147.180:59853-141.101.114.59:80                                                                 0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ?     root     37.209.147.180:52804-173.194.70.95:80                                                                  0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   1954  bw       /home/bw/.dropbox-dist/dropbox                                                              ppp0       0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ?     root     37.209.147.180:59851-141.101.114.59:80                                                                 0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ?     root     37.209.147.180:59850-141.101.114.59:80                                                                 0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ?     root     37.209.147.180:52801-173.194.70.95:80                                                                  0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   13301 bw       /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                                                                    ppp0       0.000       0.000 KB/sec
   ?     root     unknown TCP                                                                                            0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't display the owning process of these.

Does anyone recognize these addresses or is able to suggest how to troubleshoot it further or disable it? Is it some automatic update or something like that?

EDIT: per request; netstat -n, for obvious reason that normal netstat won't ever launch as all DNS requests are hogged just the same.

```
    netstat -n
    Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
    tcp        0      1 93.154.166.62:51314     198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:44098    198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:59855    141.101.114.59:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:38237    213.189.45.39:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:35167    75.101.152.29:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32939    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:55619    63.245.217.207:443      CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:60210    75.101.152.29:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32944    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:52804    173.194.70.95:80        FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:46606    23.21.151.181:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:52619    107.22.246.76:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp      415      0 93.154.146.186:36156    82.112.106.104:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:50352    107.22.246.76:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:55000    213.189.45.44:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:59853    141.101.114.59:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32937    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:56055    93.184.221.40:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp      415      0 93.154.146.186:36155    82.112.106.104:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:44097    198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:35166    75.101.152.29:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32943    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:46607    23.21.151.181:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:36422    23.21.151.181:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:36081    93.184.220.148:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:44462    213.189.45.29:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32938    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:36419    23.21.151.181:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0    497 93.154.166.62:51313     198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:59851    141.101.114.59:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:44095    198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:46611    23.21.151.181:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:38236    213.189.45.39:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0    171 37.209.147.180:45341    173.194.113.146:443     ESTABLISHED
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:52801    173.194.70.95:80        FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:36080    93.184.220.148:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:59856    141.101.114.59:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:44096    198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 93.154.166.62:57471     108.160.162.49:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:59854    141.101.114.59:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0    171 37.209.147.180:45340    173.194.113.146:443     ESTABLISHED
    tcp        0    168 37.209.147.180:45334    173.194.113.146:443     FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:46609    23.21.151.181:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0   1248 93.154.166.62:58270     64.251.23.59:443        FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        0      1 37.209.147.180:59850    141.101.114.59:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:35181    75.101.152.29:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp      232      0 93.154.172.168:46384    198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:52618    107.22.246.76:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.172.168:36298    173.194.69.95:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:60209    75.101.152.29:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0    168 37.209.147.180:45335    173.194.113.146:443     FIN_WAIT1
    tcp      415      0 93.154.146.186:36157    82.112.106.104:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:36082    93.184.220.148:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32942    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:50350    107.22.246.76:443       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 192.168.43.224:32941    199.15.160.100:80       CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        0    534 37.209.147.180:44089    198.252.206.16:80       FIN_WAIT1
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:46608    23.21.151.181:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    tcp        1      0 93.154.146.186:46612    23.21.151.181:80        CLOSE_WAIT
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:49057    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:51631    193.41.112.18:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:34827    193.41.112.18:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:35908    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:44106    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:42184    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:54485    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:42216    193.41.112.18:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:51961    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
    udp        0      0 37.209.147.180:48412    193.41.112.14:53        ESTABLISHED
```

The interesting lines from ping got lost, but the summary over past few hours is:

```
    --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
    107459 packets transmitted, 104376 received, +22 duplicates, 2% packet loss, time 195427362ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.822/528.132/90538.257/2519.263 ms, pipe 90
```

EDIT: Per request: Happened again, reboot didn't help but cleaned up all "hanging" processes. Currently netstat shows:

```
bw@pony:/var/log$ netstat -n -t
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:42767     74.125.239.143:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:50270     173.194.69.189:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45250     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:53488     173.194.32.198:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:53490     173.194.32.198:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    159 93.154.188.68:42741     74.125.239.143:443      LAST_ACK   
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45808     198.252.206.25:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:52449     173.194.32.199:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:52600     173.194.32.199:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:50300     173.194.69.189:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45253     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:46252     173.194.32.204:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45246     190.93.244.58:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:47064     173.194.113.143:443     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:34484     173.194.69.95:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45252     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:54290     173.194.32.202:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:47063     173.194.113.143:443     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:53469     173.194.32.198:80       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45242     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:53468     173.194.32.198:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:50299     173.194.69.189:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:42764     74.125.239.143:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45256     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:58047     108.160.162.105:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45249     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:50297     173.194.69.189:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:53470     173.194.32.198:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:34100     68.232.35.121:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:42758     74.125.239.143:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:42765     74.125.239.143:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:39000     173.194.69.95:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:50296     173.194.69.189:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:53467     173.194.32.198:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:42766     74.125.239.143:443      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45251     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45248     190.93.244.58:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:45247     190.93.244.58:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    159 93.154.188.68:50254     173.194.69.189:443      LAST_ACK   
tcp        0      0 93.154.188.68:34483     173.194.69.95:443       ESTABLISHED
```

Output of ps:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.8  0.0   3628  2092 ?        Ss   16:52   0:03 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [migration/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [migration/1]
root        10  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [migration/2]
root        14  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [watchdog/2]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [migration/3]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/3:0]
root        18  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [watchdog/3]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [cpuset]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [khelper]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [netns]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [kblockd]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [khubd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [md]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   16:52   0:00 [ksmd]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   16:52   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [crypto]
root        59  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        70  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/2:1]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/u:2]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/u:3]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
root        99  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [deferwq]
root       100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [charger_manager]
root       101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root       102  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/2:2]
root       106  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root       107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [usb-storage]
root       108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       109  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [usb-storage]
root       271  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/1:2]
root       316  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       317  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       440  0.1  0.0   2820   608 ?        S    16:52   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       478  0.0  0.0   3460  1648 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       632  0.0  0.0   3348  1336 ?        S    16:52   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       633  0.0  0.0   3348  1204 ?        S    16:52   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       782  0.0  0.0   2816   596 ?        S    16:52   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       822  0.0  0.0   6684  2400 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
102        834  0.2  0.0   4064  1864 ?        Ss   16:52   0:01 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root       857  0.0  0.1   7420  3380 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
root       858  0.0  0.0   4784  1636 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
syslog     860  0.0  0.0  31068  1496 ?        Sl   16:52   0:00 rsyslogd -c5
root       869  0.1  0.1  24280  5564 ?        Ssl  16:52   0:00 NetworkManager
avahi      883  0.0  0.0   3448  1488 ?        S    16:52   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [pony.local]
avahi      884  0.0  0.0   3448   436 ?        S    16:52   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root       885  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       892  0.0  0.1  25696  4140 ?        Sl   16:52   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root       923  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [scsi_eh_6]
root       959  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [krfcommd]
root       970  0.0  0.1   7536  3120 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
colord     976  0.1  0.3  55080 10396 ?        Sl   16:52   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/colord/colord
root       979  0.0  0.0   4632   872 tty4     Ss+  16:52   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       987  0.0  0.0   4632   884 tty5     Ss+  16:52   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       994  0.0  0.0   4632   884 tty2     Ss+  16:52   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       995  0.0  0.0   4632   868 tty3     Ss+  16:52   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       998  0.0  0.0   4632   876 tty6     Ss+  16:52   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root      1022  0.0  0.0   2176   680 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
root      1029  0.0  0.0   3632   664 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
daemon    1030  0.0  0.0   2476   120 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 atd
root      1031  0.0  0.0   2620   880 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 cron
root      1061  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [kworker/3:2]
root      1064  0.0  1.0  34116 31072 ?        SLsl 16:52   0:00 lightdm
root      1076 13.4  1.2 118688 37920 tty7     Ssl+ 16:52   0:55 /usr/bin/X :0 -core -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswit
root      1085  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [rts_pstor]
root      1087  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [rtsx-polling]
root      1095  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [cfg80211]
root      1127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:52   0:00 [flush-8:0]
root      1130  0.0  0.0   6136  1824 ?        Ss   16:52   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /va
root      1137  0.0  0.1  24604  3164 ?        Sl   16:52   0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root      1140  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:52   0:00 [hd-audio0]
root      1188  0.0  0.1  34308  3420 ?        Sl   16:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root      1425  0.0  0.0   4632   872 tty1     Ss+  16:52   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1443  0.1  0.1  29460  4664 ?        Sl   16:52   0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
root      1579  0.0  0.1  16540  3272 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
bw        1623  0.0  0.0   2232   644 ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/startkde
bw        1672  0.0  0.0   4092   204 ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --sh --write-env-file=/home/bw/
bw        1673  0.0  0.0   5492   384 ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --sh --write-env-file=/home/bw/.gnupg/gpg-agent-in
bw        1676  0.0  0.0   3848   792 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/startkde
bw        1677  0.5  0.0   5384  2180 ?        Ss   16:53   0:02 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
root      1704  0.3  0.1  25348  3600 ?        Sl   16:53   0:01 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
root      1705  0.0  0.0   6620   728 ?        S    16:53   0:00 udisks-daemon: not polling any devices
bw        1736  0.0  0.0   2008    64 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/start_kdeinit +kcminit_startup
bw        1737  0.0  0.5 115200 15588 ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 kdeinit4: kdeinit4 Running...                  
bw        1738  0.1  0.2 116756  8728 ?        S    16:53   0:00 kdeinit4: klauncher [kdeinit] --fd=9           
bw        1740  0.6  1.0 340524 31264 ?        Sl   16:53   0:02 kdeinit4: kded4 [kdeinit]                      
bw        1742  0.0  0.0   8944  2144 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
bw        1746  0.2  0.4  92028 14688 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/kglobalaccel
bw        1748  0.0  0.4  90804 13500 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/kwalletd
bw        1752  0.1  0.5 103764 15152 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/kactivitymanagerd
bw        1758  0.0  0.0   2144   280 ?        S    16:53   0:00 kwrapper4 ksmserver
bw        1759  0.1  0.5 150016 16088 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 kdeinit4: ksmserver [kdeinit]                  
bw        1763  2.2  1.0 178492 32100 ?        Sl   16:53   0:08 kwin
bw        1772  0.2  0.5 106292 16340 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/knotify4
bw        1777  0.9  1.1 246120 32912 ?        Sl   16:53   0:03 /usr/bin/krunner
bw        1778  6.3  2.7 389884 80216 ?        Sl   16:53   0:23 /usr/bin/plasma-desktop
bw        1785  0.0  0.0   2844  1208 ?        S    16:53   0:00 ksysguardd
bw        1789  0.1  0.4  82036 14176 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/kuiserver
bw        1805  0.3  0.1  61560  5612 ?        Sl   16:53   0:01 /usr/bin/akonadi_control
root      1806  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:53   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
bw        1808  0.1  0.2 211852  8460 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 akonadiserver
bw        1810  0.4  0.8 244116 25360 ?        Sl   16:53   0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/home/bw/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf --da
bw        1874  0.0  0.0  35284  2956 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/xsettings-kde
bw        1876  0.0  0.3  68776  9488 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/nepomukserver
bw        1884  0.4  0.9 173876 29240 ?        SNl  16:53   0:01 /usr/bin/nepomukservicestub nepomukstorage
bw        1902  6.1  2.1 451512 63924 ?        Sl   16:53   0:21 /home/bw/.dropbox-dist/dropbox
bw        1906  3.8  1.0 142368 32376 ?        Rl   16:53   0:13 /usr/bin/yakuake
bw        1933  0.0  0.1  54636  4680 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-datahub
bw        1943  0.5  1.5 164836 46836 ?        Sl   16:53   0:01 python /usr/bin/printer-applet
bw        1945  0.1  0.1  99636  5048 ?        S<l  16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
rtkit     1947  0.0  0.0  21336  1248 ?        SNl  16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
bw        1958  0.0  0.1  44204  3792 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
bw        1972  0.0  0.0  27008  2684 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
bw        1974  0.1  0.5  90480 16660 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_akonotes_resource akonadi_akonotes_res
bw        1984  0.1  0.5  90472 16636 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_akonotes_resource akonadi_akonotes_res
bw        1985  0.3  0.9 148800 28304 ?        S    16:53   0:01 /usr/bin/akonadi_archivemail_agent --identifier akonadi_archivemail_agent
bw        1992  0.1  0.5  90020 16148 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_contacts_resource akonadi_contacts_res
bw        1993  0.1  0.5  90132 16452 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_contacts_resource akonadi_contacts_res
bw        1994  0.1  0.5  90564 16332 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_ical_resource akonadi_ical_resource_0
bw        1995  0.1  0.5  90676 16732 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_ical_resource akonadi_ical_resource_1
bw        1996  0.1  0.5  90468 16800 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_agent_launcher akonadi_maildir_resource akonadi_maildir_resou
bw        1999  0.2  0.6  99324 19276 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_maildispatcher_agent --identifier akonadi_maildispatcher_agen
bw        2006  0.3  0.9 148808 28332 ?        S    16:53   0:01 /usr/bin/akonadi_mailfilter_agent --identifier akonadi_mailfilter_agent
bw        2017  0.0  0.1  50256  4716 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts
bw        2024  0.2  0.6 103632 18376 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/akonadi_nepomuk_feeder --identifier akonadi_nepomuk_feeder
bw        2043  0.0  0.0   4484   280 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /bin/cat
bw        2101  0.2  0.7 113600 22396 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1
bw        2105  0.2  0.7 114196 22072 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/nepomukcontroller
bw        2156  0.3  1.0 333188 31244 ?        Sl   16:54   0:01 /usr/bin/kmix
bw        2167  0.0  0.0   6548  2724 pts/2    Ss   16:54   0:00 /bin/bash
bw        2177  0.2  0.7 113496 22960 ?        Sl   16:54   0:00 /usr/bin/klipper
bw        2394  3.5  1.2  52932 35596 ?        SNl  16:54   0:11 /usr/bin/virtuoso-t +foreground +configfile /tmp/virtuoso_hX1884.ini +wait
root      2460  0.0  0.0   6184  1876 pts/2    S    16:54   0:00 sudo -s
root      2500  0.0  0.0   6528  2700 pts/2    S    16:54   0:00 /bin/bash
root      2599  0.0  0.0   5444  1280 pts/2    S+   16:54   0:00 /bin/bash bin/aero
root      2606  0.1  0.0   9836  2500 pts/2    S+   16:54   0:00 wvdial aero2
root      2619  0.0  0.0   3504  1280 pts/2    S    16:54   0:00 /usr/sbin/pppd 57600 modem crtscts defaultroute usehostname -detach user aero 
bw        2653  0.0  0.0   6600  2880 pts/3    Ss   16:54   0:00 /bin/bash
bw        2676  0.4  0.8 130296 24016 ?        SNl  16:54   0:01 /usr/bin/nepomukservicestub nepomukfilewatch
bw        2679  0.1  0.7 101636 22252 ?        SNl  16:54   0:00 /usr/bin/nepomukservicestub nepomukqueryservice
bw        2681  0.2  0.8 109836 24280 ?        SNl  16:54   0:00 /usr/bin/nepomukservicestub nepomukbackupsync
bw        3833 46.0  9.7 829272 288012 ?       Rl   16:55   1:46 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
bw        3903  0.0  0.0  35128  2804 ?        Sl   16:55   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
bw        4708  0.1  0.0   6564  2736 pts/4    Ss   16:56   0:00 /bin/bash
root      5210  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:57   0:00 [kworker/u:0]
root      6140  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:58   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root      6371  0.5  0.0   6184  1868 pts/4    S+   16:59   0:00 sudo nethogs ppp0
root      6411 17.7  0.2   8616  6144 pts/4    S+   16:59   0:05 nethogs ppp0
bw        6787  0.0  0.0   5464  1220 pts/3    R+   16:59   0:00 ps auxw
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `netstat|grep -i tcp` for when this happens, as well? You can crop out any connections you don't want others to see, that you might have open at the time.

Comment: @dobey: I still had my netstat dump in the scrollback; attaching.

Comment: How exactly are you connected to the Internet when that netstat was run? It looks like you have 2 separate IPs assigned to you from your ISP, at the same time.

Comment: @dobey: Probably result of my attempt to reconnect; I'm using wvdial to connect with a USB modem and ppp. Normally first suspicion is "USB modem went loose in the socket" so I restart the connection script; the provider assigns new IP on reconnect. Since that's a stupid winmodem that needs to be reconfigured to identify self as modem and not as a DVD drive with Windows drivers for the modem first, I use a script that issues the right commands before calling wvdial2. Still, that's not the source. At times I use my phone as a wifi router, and same thing happens, just on wlan0 instead of ppp0.

Comment: Reboot the system, so that it is all clear, connect once, get the data when the problem occurs, and paste that in please, instead of the current logged data.

Comment: @dobey: this occurs at quite random times and is rather hard to replicate. What kind of data would you want? Netstat doesn't show much beyond what is shown here.

Comment: Well, if it's not because your system has 3 IPs assigned to the same interface, it'd be helpful to see data which doesn't have 3 different local IPs for your system in the logs, for when it occurs. Having multiple IPs assigned to the same interface can indeed cause problems.

Comment: have you used `dig -x` and `whois` to determine what the IP addresses those connections go to are? That may give a clue as to what's spawning them.